# Getting Deprecation notice errors in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, deprecation-warning

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and PHP 7 with PhpMyAdmin (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2). I am getting a lot of deprecation notice errors.

I wanted to know is turning off errors fine?

Comment: what version of phpmyadmin? isn't there a update available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be ok - this means that some code is planned to be removed, but PHPmyadmin should be working correctly.

After update, situation can change - then you will need to adjust to situation.

Always is better to use newest version of PHP and PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You may turn off error reporting. But a better solution is Using the latest version of PMA which is 4.7.1 up to now.